# Angular radio button group make false if not selected after being selected

Tags: angularjs

I have a form that has a radio button group and the values are `ng-value = true` they are all their own entity on the model I have to work with and if a user selects one then changes their mind it still remain true. How can I make this false if deselected in an angular way?

I have a plnkr of the situation [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/7KQxwBiKxLr6OZJ7NhOL)

```
<label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio"
                   data-ng-value="true"
                   data-ng-model="vm.minorWorks.earthArTNS"
                   id="minorTns"
                   name="earthArrangements" />
            <strong> TN-S</strong>
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio"
                   data-ng-value="true"
                   data-ng-model="vm.minorWorks.earthArTNCS"
                   id="minorTncs"
                   name="earthArrangements" />
            <strong>TN-C-S</strong>
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio"
                   data-ng-value="true"
                   data-ng-model="vm.minorWorks.earthArTT"
                   id="minorTt"
                   name="earthArrangements" />
            <strong>TT</strong>
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio"
                   id="minorOther"
                   name="earthArrangements"
                   data-ng-value="true"
                   data-ng-model="vm.minorWorks.earthArOther"
                   data-ng-change="vm.minorWorks.earthArSpecify = vm.minorWorks.earthArOther ? vm.minorWorks.earthArSpecify : ''" />
            <strong>OTHER</strong>
        </label>
```

Comment: What exactly output do you want this??

Comment: if it has been checked I want it to be false as it will give me false results in the model

Comment: its not a correct way to get this output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could possibly add a function to the checkboxes, `ng-click="checkState(model)"`

and in .js

```
$scope.checkState = function(model){
    if(model) { // if model = true
        model = false; //set model to false
    }
}
```